# Glyph origins and meaning of 敢

Tags: etymology, glyph-origin

What is the meaning and etymology of the LEFT component of this character: 敢 ?

I have already checked Wiltionary and Chinese Text Project.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: http://www.vividict.com/WordInfo.aspx?id=3733  The character 敢 looks like a hand holding a hunting fork against a wild boar in Oracle writing

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
[甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
[image]
6.12.5
殷虛書契前</kbd><kbd>商
甲
[image]
2342
殷虛卜辭</kbd>

「敢」 ([Baxter-Sagart OC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese#Baxter%E2%80%93Sagart_%282014%29): **/*[k]ˤamʔ/**, *to hunt and pursue > to eagerly advance and push forward > brave*) was originally a picture of [*two hands* 「廾」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=60) fighting a [*wild pig* 「豕」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=699) with a *hunting weapon* that looked like [「干」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=59) (**/*[k]ˁar/**) or [「單」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=2488) (**/*Cə.tˤar/**), which may have simultaneously hinted at the sound. One of the hands was sometimes removed to leave behind a single [*hand* 「又」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=20).

<kbd>[西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
[金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
[image]
[大盂鼎](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Da_Yu_ding)
[集成2837](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=2837&jgwfl=)</kbd>

Later on, the weapon was corrupted into a sound hint [「甘」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=264) (**/*[k]ˤ[a]m/**).

<kbd>[戰國](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period)・[晉](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jin_(Chinese_state))
金
[image]
[中山王](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhongshan_(state)#Tombs)圓壺
[集成9734](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=9734&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>戰國・[楚](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu_(state))
[簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)
[image]
56.43
江陵九店</kbd><kbd>[東漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Eastern_Han)
[隸](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_script)
[image]
[史晨奏銘](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E5%8F%B2%E6%99%A8%E7%A2%91)</kbd>
　<kbd>今
[楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
[image]</kbd>

Another [weapon was added back to the hand to form 「攴・攵」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=31257), then the pig 「豕」 and the sound hint 「甘」 were corrupted and merged together, forming the left hand side of 「敢」.

---

**References:**

- 季旭昇《說文新證》
- [小學堂](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/)
- [國學大師](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/)

  - [郭沫若《甲骨文合集》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/)
  - [中國社會科學院考古研究所《殷周金文集成》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/)
- [中華語文知識庫](http://chinese-linguipedia.org/index.html)

  - [漢字源流](http://chinese-linguipedia.org/search_source.html)

Answer (score 1):

会意。本义:勇敢,有胆量. 同本义〖bold;courageous〗

(Logical aggregate. Original meaning: brave, having courage. [English] for the original meaning:〖bold; courageous〗

造字本义：徒手持械迎击野兽。

Original meaning of the aggregate: face beasts bare-handed armed.

Answer (score 0):

"敢" is basically never changed from Hans dynasty.

The left part is more like a man and a wild boar who is trapped. As @Tang Ho mentioned.